# What it the difference between kubernetes and azure Devops in terms of CI/CD

Tags: git, kubernetes, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I am not sure the comparison of these two. we are using Azure Devops for the CI / CD operation as a part of the project implementation. I have heard about the kubernetes . Is it same as the Azure Devops CI /CD . My question is is the CI / CD can achieved using kubernetes as well ? If we have Azure Devops then we do not need kubernetes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure DevOps is not the same as Kubernetes. Azure DevOps is used mostly for build your application and deploy them for example on Kubernetes or some Web App. Using Kubernetes you can run application in container, so running CI/CD in Kubernetes is possible when you run build process in containers but i'm not sure if it is worth the effort when you already using Azure DevOps.

In short:

- Azure DevOps - build and deploy you application
- Kubernetes - running your application (that could be deployed using Azure DevOps)